# Runtime Error illegal event name python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

When I'm running program I get this error, what does it mean?

> RuntimeError: illegal event name

Comment: We need more information to help you.  Can you post the code that causes the error, as well as the full error trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> exception RuntimeError
>
> Raised when an error is detected that doesn’t
>   fall in any of the other categories. The associated value is a string
>   indicating what precisely went wrong.